# NegativeArraySizeException occur in kotlin mp android chart

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make real-time line chart to show linear acceleration of android phone.
So, I used mp android chart library but NegativeArraySizeException occurs.

```
package com.example.graph_example

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.EntryXComparator
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Collections

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener {

    private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
    private lateinit var linearAccelerationSensor: Sensor
    private lateinit var chart : LineChart
    private lateinit var dataSetX: LineDataSet
    private lateinit var dataSetY: LineDataSet
    private lateinit var dataSetZ: LineDataSet
    private var lastX = 0.0f
    private var lastY = 0.0f
    private var lastZ = 0.0f
    private var timestamp: Double = 0.0


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        linearAccelerationSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION)

        chart = findViewById(R.id.line_chart)

        dataSetX = LineDataSet(null, "X")
        dataSetX.color = Color.RED
        dataSetX.lineWidth = 2.5f
        dataSetX.setDrawValues(false)
        dataSetX.setDrawValues(false)
        dataSetX.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER

        dataSetY = LineDataSet(null, "Y")
        dataSetY.color = Color.GREEN
        dataSetY.lineWidth = 2.5f
        dataSetY.setDrawValues(false)
        dataSetY.setDrawValues(false)
        dataSetY.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER

        dataSetZ = LineDataSet(null, "Z")
        dataSetZ.color = Color.BLUE
        dataSetZ.lineWidth = 2.5f
        dataSetZ.setDrawValues(false)
        dataSetZ.setDrawValues(false)
        dataSetZ.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER

        chart.data = LineData(dataSetX, dataSetY, dataSetZ)
        chart.description.isEnabled = false
        chart.legend.isEnabled = false
        chart.setNoDataText("Waiting for data...")
        chart.setNoDataTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        chart.setTouchEnabled(false)
        chart.isDragEnabled = false
        chart.setScaleEnabled(false)
        chart.setPinchZoom(false)
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
        chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
        chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        chart.xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, linearAccelerationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        if (event != null) {
            val x = event.values[0]
            val y = event.values[1]
            val z = event.values[2]

            val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
            if (timestamp != 0.0) {
                val dt = ((currentTime - timestamp) / 1000.0).toFloat()
                val dx = x * dt
                val dy = y * dt
                val dz = z * dt
                val pointX = Entry(lastX + dx, x.toFloat())
                val pointY = Entry(lastY + dy, y.toFloat())
                val pointZ = Entry(lastZ + dz, z.toFloat())
                dataSetX.addEntry(pointX)
                dataSetY.addEntry(pointY)
                dataSetZ.addEntry(pointZ)
                chart.notifyDataSetChanged()
                chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20.0f)
                chart.moveViewToX(dataSetX.entryCount.toFloat())
            }
            lastX += x * ((currentTime - timestamp) / 1000.0).toFloat()
            lastY += y * ((currentTime - timestamp) / 1000.0).toFloat()
            lastZ += z * ((currentTime - timestamp) / 1000.0).toFloat()
            timestamp = currentTime.toDouble()
        }
    }


    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
        // Do nothing
    }

}
```

and this is error code:

```
2023-01-02 22:13:27.370 13697-13697/com.example.graph_example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.graph_example, PID: 13697
    java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -12
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer.generateTransformedValuesLine(Transformer.java:178)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer.drawValues(LineChartRenderer.java:549)
        at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:278)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22350)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4500)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21186)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:806)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```